# SSH into Ubuntu over Serial port

Tags: ssh, serial-port

I have connected to my Ubuntu box using its serial port on windows(using putty connection is working fine.)

According to the question https://serverfault.com/questions/892892/how-to-use-ssh-over-serial-without-using-pppd-or-how-to-transfer-tcp-over-ser,
it appears I should be able to SSH into the machine over a serial port.

What packages are needed or alternatively how do I set this up?

http://patrickst.blogspot.com/2011/11/tcpip-over-slip-on-gnulinux-ubuntu.html

https://learn.adafruit.com/welcome-to-circuitpython/advanced-serial-console-on-mac-and-linux

Comment: @user68186 except I'm not transfering data but I want a shell.

Comment: @user68186 Both do not have ethernet.  A crossover cable has been eliminated do to other technical reasons.

Comment: You'd need to have TCP/IP over serial

Comment: @William what do you mean by "putty connection is working fine", If you are unable to ssh into it.

Comment: @PrathuBaronia it just spits back machine info

Comment: @William what happens when you press "Open" after configuring the connection?

Comment: Is that ssh really needed to secure link?

Comment: @TadejP I'm not sure

Comment: I can elaborate this answer for Linux inside Virtualization on Linux host or Linux connected with serial port to Linux using `socat` and `pppd`. But since it looks you have different configuration I thing simplest way is to use:

    # sudo systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
    # sudo systemctl start serial-getty@ttyS0.service

For systemd systems

Answer (score 1):

SSH is meant to accept (secure) connections over TCP/IP. To use SSH over a serial port, you'd need something acting as a TCP client and "forwarding" data from/to the serial port, such as `socat`.

This ([source](https://serverfault.com/a/911077)) should be enough, assuming `/dev/ttyS1` is your serial port, `115200` is the desired baud rate ("Speed" when using PuTTY for Serial connection) and you have `sshd` listening on port `22` (which is the default):

```
socat -d -d tcp:127.0.0.1:22 file:/dev/ttyS1,b115200
```

`-d -d`, according to [the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat):

> Prints fatal, error, warning, and notice messages.

I have not tested this, as I do not have a serial port at the moment.

**If you just need login and run shell commands over the serial port**, you can run `getty`, `agetty` or even `screen` on a serial port. 
The [SerialConsoleHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SerialConsoleHowto) guide is outdated, but [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/843736) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, why do you need ssh, when you are on the shell in the serial port? Normally, you use the serial port, because, you want to see the device output and access its shell, and you use ssh when the machine is far, far away from you physically. If you still want, please go ahead and connect a RJ45 cable from the device to the computer where SSH is installed. I am assuming, you have set up proper IP networking and installed SSH server. Because, SSH works over the TCP on port 22. And in doing so, you are going to miss some serial output, because, SSH (Secure Shell) only gives you a sell. Use both and know the difference. Hope that helps!

Answer (score -3):

1. Download putty.exe from [here](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html).
2. You should know the number of COM port and the baud rate of the port.

   - If you don't know both, try to fix speed at 115200 then try COM1 to COM8.
3. Start putty.exe

   - Choose "Serial" in "Connection type"
   - Set baud rate in "Speed"
   - Set COM port name in "Serial line"
   - Press "Open"

[image: Putty]

Comment: On Ubuntu box also install and configure openssh package. Should be running on same tty as you have serial connection. Look in dmesg for the tty number then put it in your openssh configuration.

Comment: Yes this is how I am connected to the device using serial but unfortunately by default serial doesn't support sshing into the machine.